# How to resolve Error org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION exception in java ?

Tags: java, corba, idl

When I invoke method on client side, for distributed reference object, I have this message error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION:
        at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._get_delegate(ObjectImpl.java:18)
        at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_local(ObjectImpl.java:130)
        at fr.esiag.commun._ManageDemandStub.createDemand(_ManageDemandStub.java
:28)
        at fr.esiag.commun.resource.MyInvocationHandler.invoke(MyInvocationHandl
er.java:29)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createDemand(Unknown Source)
        at org.TD.TransactionDriver.main(TransactionDriver.java:55)
```

Can someone tell me what that means ?

Answer (score 5):

BAD_OPERATION expception happens when you try to call a method that dosen't exist in the servant. I think you cast (instead of narrow) the remote object wrong. Maybe it's is relative to your  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686072/how-can-i-recognize-that-the-object-is-instance-of-an-interface-when-passed-in-p#20686072)